# asp net mvc - pasar información de JS al controlador

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo este modelo de datos

```
public partial class Ventas
{
    public Ventas()
    {
        this.Caja = new HashSet<Caja>();
        this.Montajes = new HashSet<Montajes>();
        this.VentasLinias = new HashSet<VentasLinias>();
    }

    public int idCliente { get; set; }
    public byte tiendaCliente { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string observaciones { get; set; }
    public decimal total { get; set; }
    public decimal subTotal { get; set; }
     

    public virtual ICollection<Caja> Caja { get; set; }
    public virtual Clientes Clientes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Montajes> Montajes { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuarios Usuarios { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<VentasLinias> VentasLinias { get; set; }
}
```

La relación es 1 **Venta** --> N **VentasLinias**

El javascript intento pasar 2 objetos uno con la cabecera de la venta y el otro con una lista de las linias

```
    if (isAllValid) {
        var venta = {
            OrderDateString: $('#orderDate').val().trim(),
            Description: $('#description').val().trim(),
            totalCobrar: $("#totalCobrado").val().trim(),
            totalVenta: $("#totalVenta").val().trim(),
        }

        var linias = {
            OrderDetails: list
        }


        $(this).val('Please wait...');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Ventas/guardarVenta',
            data: JSON.stringify(venta,linias),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.estado) {
                    alert('Venta creada correctamente');
                    //here we will clear the form
                    list = [];
                    $('#orderNo,#orderDate,#description').val('');
                    $('#orderdetailsItems').empty();
                }
                else {
                    alert('Error');
                }
                $('#submit').val('Save');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                $('#submit').val('Save');
            }
        });
```

Y el controlador recibe dos parámetros uno para cada objeto

```
    public JsonResult guardarVenta(Ventas venta,VentasLinias linias)
    {
        bool estado = false;


        try
        {
            db.Ventas.Add(venta);
            db.SaveChanges();
            estado = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            estado = false;
        }

        return new JsonResult { Data = new { estado = estado } };
   }
```

Mis pregunta es  , al tener la relación 1 a N , seria mejor pasar solo un objeto Venta y dentro de "el" una lista de VentasLinias , de ser asin que cambios debo hacer , no consigo verlo.

## Actualización

He modificado el código de esta forma

**Controlador**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult guardarVenta(Ventas venta,List<VentasLinias> linias)
    {
        bool estado = false;
```

Y en la parte del **Javascript**

```
      if (isAllValid) {
        var venta = {
            OrderDateString: $('#orderDate').val().trim(),
            Description: $('#description').val().trim(),
            total: $("#totalCobrado").val().trim(),
            subTotal: $("#totalVenta").val().trim(),
            numeroFactura: '33'
        }

        var linias = {
            OrderDetails: list
        }

        var data = {
            venta: venta,
            linias: linias
        }

        
        $(this).val('Please wait...');


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Ventas/guardarVenta',
            
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
        
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.estado) {
                    alert('Venta creada correctamente');
                    //here we will clear the form
                    list = [];
                    $('#orderNo,#orderDate,#description').val('');
                    $('#orderdetailsItems').empty();
                }
                else {
                    alert('Error');
                }
                $('#submit').val('Save');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error.responseText);
                $('#submit').val('Save');
            }
        });
    }
```

Ahora recibo la petición en en controlador , pero tal como muestro en las capturas la lista  de VentasLinias es nula , y aquí si que no veo el problema...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al enviar los datos únicamente estás especificando un solo objeto en el `data` del Ajax Request, tienes que separar la información en dos objetos y luego *`stringificar`* cada uno de ellos:

```
data: {
    venta: JSON.stringify(venta),
    linias: JSON.stringify(linias)
}
```

Para que finalmente, el Ajax completo quede así:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Ventas/guardarVenta',
    data: {
        venta: JSON.stringify(venta),
        linias: JSON.stringify(linias)
    }
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.estado) {
            alert('Venta creada correctamente');
            //here we will clear the form
            list = [];
            $('#orderNo,#orderDate,#description').val('');
            $('#orderdetailsItems').empty();
        }
        else {
            alert('Error');
        }
        $('#submit').val('Save');
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        $('#submit').val('Save');
    }
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias , he probado tu solución propuesta pero no me llega a hacer la llamada al controlador me entra en function(error) y me da este error si hago un error.responseText

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>Primitivo JSON no v&#225;lido: venta.</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

Comment: @ilernet ¿es decir que la petición nunca llega al `Controller` y se va directo al `error` del Ajax Request?

Comment: si , exacto , pongo otra respuesta con el código modificado

Comment: @ilernet no, mejor edita la pregunta, esto para mantener la integridad de *pregunta-respuesta* :D

Comment: ok gracias @Flxtr

Comment: gracias a todos ya lo he resuelto